# What code can I use if I have ten numbers and I want to produce 1000 different randomly shuffled orders of the the ten numbers

Tags: python, random, permutation, shuffle

I can use this to find all of the possible options, however, I want a random sample of 1000 from this set:

```
items = range(1,11)
//from itertools import permutations
//for p in permutations(items):
print(p)
```

Comment: [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample)

Comment: Why are you using and tagging permutations? Permutations aren't random. What do they have to do with random sampling?

Comment: I am guessing he wanted a 1000 random samples from that list of permutations.

Comment: `import random` module and then `n_items = random.sample(permutations(items), 1000)`

Comment: I have a suggested solution below. I show an arbitrary list of 10 numbers just to show that the original list can be any 10 numbers. You can just have num_list = range(1,11), and it will still work.

Comment: Permutations include duplicated combinations. I assume you' d like to start with unique combinations. After that, would you allow duplicated orders? That is what random would possibly produce. As it is, the question is unclear imo.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggested solution. Based on your requirements, the list of 10 numbers are already chosen, and you just want to have a list that will have those 10 numbers shuffled in 1000 unique ways. So below, I have a list of 10 numbers. The random.sample(num_list,10), will select those 10 numbers at random, and create a new list. Since the list has only 10 numbers, it selects all 10 in random order and creates the new list. It checks the overall answer list to see if that order had been selected before. If it hasn't, it adds it to the list. It does this until 1000 unique orders have been found:

```
import random
num_list = [6, 9, 1000, 53, 321, 8, -5, 714, 0, 2120]
answer_list = []
while len(answer_list) != 1000:
    new_sample = random.sample(num_list, 10)
    if new_sample not in answer_list:
        answer_list.append(new_sample)
```

So after running the script here are the last 5 items on the list and the first 5 items on the list:

```
==== RESTART: C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/scripts/Stack_overflow/ransom.py ====
>>> answer_list[-5:]
[[0, 9, 8, 53, 321, 1000, -5, 6, 2120, 714],
 [714, 0, 2120, 6, -5, 53, 8, 321, 9, 1000],
 [6, -5, 53, 321, 0, 1000, 2120, 8, 9, 714],
 [321, 53, 9, 8, 2120, 714, 0, 1000, -5, 6],
 [1000, 53, 2120, 6, 8, 9, -5, 714, 321, 0]]
>>> answer_list[:5]
[[321, 9, 714, -5, 53, 6, 1000, 8, 0, 2120],
 [0, 6, 2120, -5, 714, 9, 1000, 8, 53, 321],
 [1000, 8, 9, 6, 53, 321, 2120, 714, 0, -5],
 [9, 0, 321, 6, 714, 53, 1000, 2120, -5, 8],
 [6, 1000, 321, 0, -5, 2120, 8, 714, 9, 53]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `set` guarantees the uniqueness of its elements, you can generate permutations via `random.sample()` and attempt adding the result until the size of the set gets up to the desired quantity:

```
import random

a = range(1,11)
solutions = set()
while len(solutions) < 1000:
    solutions.add(tuple(random.sample(a, 10)))
```

At this point `solutions` contains a set of tuples which are unique permutations. A variation on the theme uses shuffling rather than sampling:

```
import random

a = list(range(1,11))
solutions = set()
while len(solutions) < 1000:
    random.shuffle(a)
    solutions.add(tuple(a))
```

If you want a list of lists rather than a set of tuples, append the following after the `while` loop:

```
lols = [list(x) for x in solutions]
```

Given that you want 1000 out of the 10! (which is 3628800) permutations, the risk of collisions is close to zero.  The expected number of iterations of the loop is 1000 plus a small fraction, less than 1001.

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain what you think is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Python's permutation module only provides a way to iterate through the 3-million-plus permutations, and not a way to pick one arbitrarily by order.  You'll need something like this:

```
def kthperm(S, k):
    P = []
    while S != []:
        f = math.factorial(len(S)-1)
        i = int(math.floor(k/f))
        x = S[i]
        k = k%f
        P.append(x)
        S = S[:i] + S[i+1:]
    return P
```

Now you can pick a random number from 0 to 10!-1, compute that permutation directly, and add it to your list, as many times as needed:

```
perms = []
for i in range(1000):
    perms.append(kthperm(list(range(1,11)),
      random.randint(0,math.factorial(10)-1))
```